# Javascript: new Date() initialized with specific date string returns two different dates in different timezones

Tags: javascript, date, localization, timezone

I am using new Date() to create a date object for a specific date. But it returns two different dates in different timezones. See below:

**When my machine is in Indian Timezone (IST)**

```js
console.log(new Date('2020-08-28')); //returns Fri Aug 28 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

**When my machine is in US timezone (CST)**

```js
console.log(new Date('2020-08-28')); //returns Fri Aug 27 2020 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

How is this happening even when I am telling the JS to create a date for a given string? The string here is '2020-08-28'.

Why is this happening and how to ignore the timezone in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the ECMAScript specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-date.parse):

> When the UTC offset representation is absent, date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and date-time forms are interpreted as a local time.

The forms themselves are described in the [Date Time String Format](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format).

It is important to note that treating date-only forms as UTC is in conflict with the ISO 8601 spec which treats such forms as local time.  This is a known issue and [was done deliberately](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/138) in the name of "web reality".

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate a `Date` by passing a string, it's supposed to be a full [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string which specifies the time zone. As you dont specify it, it takes Greenwich Mean Time (±00:00), then uses your local timezone when displaying it. Use this if you want to display the date as GMT:

```js
console.log(new Date('2020-08-28').toUTCString());
```

Comment: What if I pass new Date('2020-08-28T00:00:00')?

Comment: My answer was actually wrong, please take a look at the edit